# Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Tags: android

I can't find any other android API in the project. it is showing only API 20 Android 4.4W. how do i overcome from it?

Comment: [how-to-solve-exception-raised-during](http://thodorisbais.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-solve-exception-raised-during.html) have you downloaded other other SDK or APIs through Android SDK Manager

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The issue is because you are using the API level 20 for wearable devices. You need to download other sdk through the Android SDK Manager.

In Eclipse, open windows->android sdk manager->select Android 4.4.2 and check Android sdk and ARM system image and click install packages

Now you have the API level 19 source code so eclipse will now be able to render the views

Now go to the graphical layout tab of the layout and change the android version from 20 to 19.

Answer (score 19):

In `Android Studio` you just need to change your `graphical layout API` from `4.4w` to `4.4.2` as in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Within the eclipse you can change the API version of the design layout. This worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you using Android Studio 
1 Open your Build.gradle
2 change values as you need 
like this

> android {
>       compileSdkVersion 17
>       buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     applicationId "com.example.xxx.xxxx"
>     minSdkVersion 16
>     targetSdkVersion 17
>     versionCode 1
>     versionName "1.0"
> }
> ```

3 press Sync Project with gradle file..
4 if you do not have that API it will ask you to download.. 
  rebuild the project..